# No root path can be found for the provided module "builtins" in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have python3.5.2 as my default python and i installed flask. Then i wrote a basic flaskapp.py to try and i have encountered this error:

**RuntimeError: No root path can be found for the provided module "builtins".  This can happen because the module came from an import hook that does not provide file name information or because it's a namespace package.  In this case the root path needs to be explicitly provided.**

Here is my flaskapp.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('pages/pages/home/home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    app.run()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<input>", line 6, in <module> File "C:\....\flask\app.py", line 345, 
in init root_path=root_path) 
File "C:\...\flask\helpers.py", line 843, 
in init root_path = get_root_path(self.import_name) 
File "C:\...\flask\helpers.py", line 721, 
in get_root_path 'provided.' % import_name) RuntimeError:
```

Answer (score 3):

This sentence

'No root path can be found for the provided module "builtins"'

is they trouble maker.. I assume you are running this in some IDE line by line, because I encoutered the same problem using IntelliJ and the python console.

Please check the value of the argument `__name__` in this case. This will probably have the value "builtins".
However, when you actually *run* the full script, then the `__name__` argument will be set to `__main__`.

Comment: I thought that setting `__name__ = '__main__'` from the Python prompt before running the script also solved it for me. However, on further exploration, it did not. Flask could start, but it could not find the templates folder unless I ran it with PyCharm's "Run" option with "Run with Python console" turned off in the run configurations.

Answer (score 3):

You dont run this in your IDE. You run it in the command line. Go to the folder where your flaskapp.py file is and run `py flaskapp.py`. Read more here: https://github.com/bev-a-tron/MyFlaskTutorial/blob/master/1_start.rst